# Dragging a column to the leftmost

Tags: r, cran, dendextend

I am a newbie on R and my question may be too simple. I am trying to draw a hierarchical cluster. I use readxl to read the data from a xlsx file. The dendextend package also includes the year column to calculations. I want to drag the year column to leftmost as seen in   [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S0Sz.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create rownames from the year column (for whatever reason), you can just use

```
rownames(your_df) <- your_df$Year
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.